# Cartopy: coastlines not lining up with imshow projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I'm trying to produce a figure in Python that will line up the map coastlines from Cartopy with a RGB projection using satellite data (POLDER) that is fixed to Sinusoidal grid.

I have tried both Matplotlib's Basemap and Cartopy, and have had better luck with Cartopy, however even after following other people's code, the coastlines do not match up.

What I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.Sinusoidal(central_longitude=0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

# set image extents using the min and max of lon at lat
# image_extent ~= [-73.25, -10, 59.5, 84]
min_lon = np.nanmin(subset_lon)
max_lon = np.nanmax(subset_lon)
min_lat = np.nanmin(subset_lat)
max_lat = np.nanmax(subset_lat)

extents = proj.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), np.array([min_lon, max_lon]), 
                                               np.array([min_lat, max_lat]))
img_extents = [extents[0][0], extents[1][0], extents[0][1], extents[1][1]] 

ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
# # image RGB
ax.imshow(RGB, origin='upper', extent=img_extents, transform=proj))

ax.set_xmargin(0.05)
ax.set_ymargin(0.10)
ax.coastlines(color='white')

plt.show()
```

Produces:
[this figure where the coastlines do NOT match up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAtI8.png)

[image: output_image]

[Figure with central_lon as -20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhgk6.png)

[Figure using only imshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM71Q.png)

I know the projection has to be sinusoidal, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Any ideas on what else it could be or tips on how to fix it?

Here is the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vRLKmeAXzCk5cLCJ1syOt7EJnaTmIwOa/view

And code to extract the data and make the image that I would like overlayed with the cartopy coastlines:

```
data = SD(path_to_file, SDC.READ)
subset_lat = data.select('subset_lat')[:]
subset_lon = data.select('subset_lon')[:]
R = data.select('mband07')[:]
G = data.select('mband02')[:]
B = data.select('mband01')[:]
RGB = np.dstack((R, G, B))
plt.imshow(RGB)
```

** Edited to add on two comments and code to make imshow RGB image.

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably need to specify value of the central meridian for `ccrs.Sinusoidal()` in your code.

Comment: I guess your image does not come in Sinusoidal projection... use the `transform` argument to specify the projection of the data!

Comment: @raphael I've added both of your comments and it is still not lined up.

Comment: What do you get with `proj = ccrs.Sinusoidal(central_longitude=-20)`?

Comment: @Olivia if you provide a link to the data I can try to have a look what's going on here...

Comment: @swatchai I updated the a link to show an image where I change to -20. It seems like the coastlines don't match up because the image is being stretched...

Comment: @Olivia Please try again with -90.

Comment: @swatchai when I change to -90 nothing shows up... It just ends up being a very thin black line

Comment: @Olivia Could you provide a link to the dataset? Otherwise it is not possible to test locally for a possible solution.

Comment: @molinav here is the dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vRLKmeAXzCk5cLCJ1syOt7EJnaTmIwOa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @raphael I just posted the data above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had a look at the data and I think the problem actually comes from the fact that your data is NOT provided in an equidistant raster!
Therefore using imshow is problematic since it will introduce distortions... (note that imshow will just divide your extent into equally sized pixels based on the number of datapoints, irrespective of the actual coordinates!)

To clarify what I mean... I'm pretty sure the data you have is provided in the grid described here (page 13):

https://www.theia-land.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/parasol_te_level-3_format-i2.00.pdf

I have personally never encountered this kind of grid-definition, but it seems that the number of pixels per latitude is adjusted to account for distortions... to quote from the document above:

> Along a parallel, the step is chosen in order to have a resolution as constant as possible. The number of pixels from 180°W to 180°E is chosen equal to 2 x NINT[3240 cos(latitude)] where NINT stands for nearest
> integer.

To quickly visualize the data I'd therefore suggest to use a scatterplot + the actual coordinates instead of imshow!

---

Alternatively, I'm developing a `matplotlib`+ `cartopy` based plotting library ([EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)) that is intended to simplify visualizations from irregular or non-uniformly gridded datasets such as yours...

After reprojection to Sinusoidal projection, one can see that the distance between the pixel-centers is at least nearly equal...

[image]

So we can use this information to visualize the data as rectangles in Sinusoidal projection with a size of 6200x6200... yielding the expected image:

[image]

... and zooming in certainly shows that those pixels have approximately the same size but they are definitely not equally distributed!
[image]

... here's the code to create the above plot with EOmaps:

```py
from eomaps import Maps
import numpy as np
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

data = SD("Copy of greenland_PM01_L2.2007061414150564.058140.1.46-public-release.hdf", SDC.READ)

# ---- get the actual coordinates of your datapoints
lon, lat = data.select("subset_lon")[:], data.select("subset_lat")[:]
# mask nan-values
mask = np.logical_and(np.isfinite(lon), np.isfinite(lat))
lon, lat = lon[mask], lat[mask]

# ---- get the colors you want to use
R = data.select("mband07")[:][mask]
G = data.select("mband02")[:][mask]
B = data.select("mband01")[:][mask]
RGB = list(zip(R, G, B)) # a list of rgb-tuples

# ---- plot the data
m = Maps(Maps.CRS.Sinusoidal())
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.set_shape.rectangles(radius=3100, radius_crs=Maps.CRS.Sinusoidal())
# use "dummy" values since we provide explicit colors
m.set_data(data=np.empty(lon.shape), xcoord=lon, ycoord=lat, crs=4326)
m.plot_map(set_extent=True, color=RGB)
```

... and with this approach also the coastlines are located where they are supposed to be!
[image]

Comment: Very interesting the point about the geolocation "grid". First time that I see this kind of implementation for the pixels.

Comment: I've tried to implement a bit more flexible and intuitive ways for geo-data visualization in [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) since I found myself limited quite a bit by the possibilities provided by `imshow`, `scatter` and `contourf` (especially when it comes to non-rectangular datasets, or when you need to take care about distortions in your pixels etc.).

Comment: Concerning the grid I was quite puzzled myself... it seems like an odd grid definition, but I'm sure they have some kind of reason for that...

Comment: @raphael How would I change the code so I can change the projection of the coastlines? If I changed the projection would the coastlines still match up?

Comment: @raphael I was finally able to install eosmaps but I get an error when using Maps. When I set m = Maps(Maps.CRS.Sinusoidal()) I get the error: AttributeError: 'ListedColormap' object has no attribute 'copy'. This happens if I call Maps() as well.

Comment: @Olivia hey, the final projection of the map is set on initialization, e.g. `m = Maps(crs=...)`, and yes, coastlines and datapoints will be reprojected accordingly.

Comment: your installation issue very much sounds like you're using an outdated version of matploltib... if you open an issue on [github](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) and provide some details on your environment and how you installed the package I can try to help

Comment: @raphael I updates everything on conda and it worked like a charm thank you!!

Comment: @Olivia nice, glad I could help :-) (how about accepting the answer then?)

Answer (score 0):

The issue consists of two parts:

- You need to compute the extents in the projected space and not in the latitude/longitude space, because there is not a direct correspondence between limit coordinates.
- You need to know the reference longitude of your sinusoidal projection, but unfortunately it is not available in your dataset metadata. A manual inspection showed me that it is somewhere around -14 or -15 degrees.

To solve this by means of `basemap`, you need a bit of hacking because at the moment `Basemap` does not support extents for sinusoidal projection (i.e. it is always set to the whole globe). But you can update the extent by hand both in the `Basemap` object and the underlying `Axes` object and then it should work:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from pyhdf.SD import SD
from pyhdf.SD import SDC

# Open dataset file.
path = "Greenland_PM01_L2.2007061414150564.058140.1.46-public-release.hdf"
data = SD(path, SDC.READ)

# Read latitude/longitude coordinates.
subset_lat = data.select("subset_lat")[:]
subset_lon = data.select("subset_lon")[:]

# Read RGB image.
R = data.select("mband07")[:]
G = data.select("mband02")[:]
B = data.select("mband01")[:]
RGB = np.dstack((R, G, B))

# Create `Basemap` object to plot the RGB image.
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
bmap1 = Basemap(projection="sinu", resolution="i", lon_0=-14, ax=ax1)

# Set image extents in the projected space. The hack here is that we
# update the corners by hand in both the `Axes` and `Basemap` objects.
x, y = bmap1(subset_lon, subset_lat)
llcrnrx, urcrnrx = np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x)
llcrnry, urcrnry = np.nanmin(y), np.nanmax(y)
bmap1.llcrnrx, bmap1.llcrnry = llcrnrx, llcrnry
bmap1.urcrnrx, bmap1.urcrnry = urcrnrx, urcrnry
ax1.set_xlim(llcrnrx, urcrnrx)
ax1.set_ylim(llcrnry, urcrnry)

# Now we can call `imshow`. The keyword argument `origin` does not work
# here, so we can simply reverse the image rows.
bmap1.drawcoastlines(color="white", linewidth=0.5)
bmap1.imshow(RGB[::-1])

# We can also play with the land cover image and check how well the
# coastlines are fitting.
landcover = data.select("subset_land")[:]

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
bmap2 = Basemap(projection="sinu", resolution="i", lon_0=-14, ax=ax2)
bmap2.llcrnrx, bmap2.llcrnry = llcrnrx, llcrnry
bmap2.urcrnrx, bmap2.urcrnry = urcrnrx, urcrnry
ax2.set_xlim(llcrnrx, urcrnrx)
ax2.set_ylim(llcrnry, urcrnry)

bmap2.drawcoastlines(color="red", linewidth=0.5)
bmap2.imshow(landcover[::-1])
```

which shows this RGB:
[image: Greenland RGB sinusoidal]

and this land cover:
[image: Greenland RGB landcover]

The coastlines match better in the South than in the North, but I am not sure if this is just a limitation of the instrument itself (plus the uncertainty in the correct reference longitude).

Comment: basemap has been depreciated since 2016 and is out of maintenance since 2020!  (see https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/intro.html#cartopy-new-management-and-eol-announcement)   ... also I added a bit of explanation in my answer why imshow is not a particularly good choice for this kind of data (which also explains why your coastlines do not match up properly in the north...)

Comment: @raphael The `basemap` documentation is actually outdated and needs to be regenerated. I am the main `basemap` maintainer since December 2021, and I can confirm you that `basemap` is **not** EOL. ;-)

Comment: oh... interesting :-D is there a particular reason for the decision to revive (or continue) basemap despite of cartopy?

Comment: Basically I maintain a private project in which `basemap` is a core dependency, so I am tidying up `basemap` to at least ensure that it is easily installable (e.g. available precompiled wheels for different platforms), as well as applying patches and corrections whenever something appears. Based on this question I will probably apply a patch in `basemap`, since it is definitely counter-intuitive for this use case.

Comment: Also, `cartopy` became Python-3-only before it was actually stable, and there is still a lot of Python 2 code around, which `basemap` does support. This does not mean that I support developing Python 2 applications, but you never know in which server you will need to deploy...

Comment: ah, ok yep that makes a lot of sense! it probably takes some more decades for python2  to disappear :-D

Comment: Myself I do not write Python 2 code any more. I write only Python 3 code that happens to be Python-2 compatible. The breaking changes from Python 2 to Python 3 had a reason. Unfortunately, there are still some wild servers around in which Python 2.7 is the most sensible option to take (w.r.t Python 3.2 for example), and in which I have no control but for deploying packages. In this (still happening) situation, `basemap` has a value.

Comment: @molinav i am getting an error with the bounds saying: ValueError: Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf. Did you not have this issue?

Comment: @Olivia I am running the code just as shown in the reply. Could you provide a bit more information, e.g. which line is causing this ValueError to appear? My Python environment is the following: python: 3.8.12, numpy: 1.22.2, matplotlib: 3.5.1, basemap: 1.3.2, pyhdf: 0.10.3.

Comment: @molinav I ma using python 3.6.10, basemap 1.2.2, matplotlib 3.2.2, pyhdf 0.10.2, and numpy 1.17.0. The problem is when I am setting the axis with ax1.set_xlim(llcrnrx, urcrnrx) and  ax1.set_ylim(llcrnry, urcrnry) since basemap is setting some of the limits equal to inf. If i change the code a bit, the coordinates end up being over India.

Comment: @Olivia (llcrnrx, urcrnrx) should return you (17817680.4744429, 19793946.731868267), and (llcrnry, urcrnry) should return you (16632899.80369196, 19344819.28476555). If that is not the case, there must be something broken in one of the libraries.